# Why do we need "smaller $\sigma -$algebra" for random variable?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ a random variable. Why the $\sigma -$algebra generate by $X$ is interesting ? (i.e. $\sigma (X)$). For example, we throw a  dice. Let $X$ denote the result. Why $\sigma (X)$ is more significant than the Borel 
$\sigma -$algebra ?

Comment: What is the "tribute" in this context?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Borel tribute"? Also I am not familiar with the term "tribute" in this context.

Comment: I guess a $\sigma$-algebra maybe?

Comment: Are you French ? The translation of tribu is $\sigma$-algebra, not tribute.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $\sigma -$algebra (yes I'm french).

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable defined on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ then $\sigma(X)\subseteq\mathcal A$. In that sense $\sigma(X)$ is "smaller" than $\mathcal A$. But if $\mathcal A$ is not a collection of Borel sets (and mostly it is not) then there is no comparing with Borelsets (actually $\sigma(X)$ is the collection of preimages under $X$ of the Borel sets) at all.

Answer (score 1):

If $E,F\in\sigma(X)$ and $E\neq F$ then *exactly one* of these events can occur.

If $B,C\in\mathcal B$ then $B\neq C$ does not exclude that the events $\{X\in B\}$ and $\{X\in C\}$ are the same (so that both occur or both occur not).

E.g. in the example you give we have $\{X\in(0.5,2)\}=\{X=1\}$.

It is more handsome to work with a collection $\sigma(X)=\{\{X\in B\}\mid B\in\mathcal B\}$ then with a family $(\{X\in B\})_{B\in\mathcal B}$. This especially in the knowledge that lots of family members can be the same.